Hosting .NET 8 Blazor Web App with ASP.NET API
I'm Building a small Website atm. For the Frontend I am using the new .NET 8 Blazor Web App with SSR and for the Backend and .NET 8 ASP.NET API. Is it still possible to host the Blazor Web App with the ASP.NET Backend, like in the old .NET 7 "ASP.NET HOSTET BLAZER WASM" and how?
I tried the old approach of .NET 7 but this doesn't work because there is no index.html anymore.
This is my Programm.cd of the ASP.NET API.
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<DockerService>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}

app.Urls.Add("http://localhost:5000");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();


I have added the Frontend as Reverence like in .NET 7.
